# How to find a maximum?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

```
FindMaximum[1/2*Abs[(o - u)^2/(1 + o^2 + u^2 + 2*o*u + 2*o^2*u^2)]^2, {o, u}]
```

doesn't work. It gave me that :

> FindMaximum::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a maximum; it may be a minimum or a saddle point.

Comment: A `ContourPlot` would help at it appears there are two points that result in a maximum:  `ContourPlot[
 1/2*Abs[(o - u)^2/(1 + o^2 + u^2 + 2*o*u + 2*o^2*u^2)]^2, {o, -4, 
  4}, {u, -4, 4}]`

Comment: Try `NMaximize[
 1/2*Abs[(o - u)^2/(1 + o^2 + u^2 + 2*o*u + 2*o^2*u^2)]^2, {o, u}]`.

Comment: `NMaximize[
 1/2*Abs[(o - u)^2/(1 + o^2 + u^2 + 2*o*u + 2*o^2*u^2)]^2, {o, u}, 
 Method -> "RandomSearch"]` finds the other one.

Comment: `Maximize` works as well, giving both solutions

Answer (score 3):

A [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) helps in picking good starting values for `FindMaximum`:

```
DensityPlot[
 1/2*Abs[(o - u)^2/(1 + o^2 + u^2 + 2*o*u + 2*o^2*u^2)]^2, {o, -5, 5}, 
 {u, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Then using the aproximate values from the `DensityPlot` [`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) locates one of the points

```
FindMaximum[
 1/2*Abs[(o - u)^2/(1 + o^2 + u^2 + 2*o*u + 2*o^2*u^2)]^2, {{o, -1}, {u, 1}}]
```

> {1., {o -> -0.840896, u -> 0.840896}}

And the other point is at the opposite sign of `o` and `u`

Another option is:

```
NMaximize[
 1/2*Abs[(o - u)^2/(1 + o^2 + u^2 + 2*o*u + 2*o^2*u^2)]^2, {o, u}]
```

Comment: Alternatively, one could locate the extrema in this way: `ContourPlot[Thread[D[((o - u)^2/(1 + o^2 + u^2 + 2*o*u + 2*o^2*u^2))^2/2, {{o, u}}] == 0] // Evaluate, {o, -5, 5}, {u, -5, 5}]`

Comment: thank you so much , it works , i appreciate, thanks again